# Django - Foreign Key on non-unique field

Tags: python, django

Consider two models:

```py
from django.db import models


class File(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=False)

class Comment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    file_name = models.ForeignKey(to=File, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="name")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=False)
```

and some data:

```py
f1 = File.objects.create(id=1, name="a.xlsx")
f2 = File.objects.create(id=2, name="a.xlsx")
f3 = File.objects.create(id=3, name="b.xlsx")
c1 = Comment.objects.create(id=1, file_name="a.xlsx", comment="Comment 1")
c2 = Comment.objects.create(id=2, file_name="a.xlsx", comment="Comment 2")
c3 = Comment.objects.create(id=2, file_name="b.xlsx", comment="Comment 3")
```

From the above:

- `f1` is associated to two comments: `c1` and `c2`
- `f2` is also associated to two comments: `c1` and `c2`
- `f3` is associated to one comment: `c3`

But according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field), `ForeignKey.to_field` requires `File.name` to be unique but that's not the case. How can I achieve this relationship **without creating any intermediary tables**?

So ideally:

- `f1.comments` would return `c1` and `c2`
- `c1.files` would return `f1` and `f2`
  etc

**EDIT**:
`File.name` must remain the foreign relationship field in `Comment` so a solution suggesting to change this to `File.id` doesn't help resolve this question.

Comment: i realise that `on_delete=models.CASCADE` probably doesn't make sense in this instance. I guess I'd be looking for a `on_delete=DO_NOTHING`

Comment: As @Hill's answer shows below,, don't use name as the foreign key. Use the File's id instead. In fact, there is no reason to declare id yourself. Django takes care fo that for you

Comment: re-name as foreign key: i dont have a choice, legacy system.
re-ids: sure! I put it in the code above for some transparency.

Comment: Does your legacy code already declare `name` as a `ForeignKey`? I'm pretty sure SQL requires a foreign key to reference a unique field in the other table. So this isn't going to work the way you want.

Comment: No, the legacy code declares `name` as `varchar` so SQL is not aware of this being a FK.

Comment: The fact that `name` is `type `varchar` has nothing to do with whether or not it is a foreign key. Nor does it prevent you from using `id` as a foreign key instead. I assume you are referring to `name` in the `File` class. Or do you mean `file_name` in the `Comment` class?

Answer (score 1):

Django does not allow referring to non-unique field in foreign key, which is a bad practice anyway. However, if you still want to refer to the foreign table with non-unique field then instead of creating a foreign key you can treat file_name as a normal attribute and then override delete and save functions of File and Comment models accordingly.

For example, if you want to achieve on_delete=CASCADE functionality of foreign key then you can override delete function of the File model and delete related comments in this function. Here is how you can declare your models

```
from django.db import models


class File(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=False)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # you might want to add some conditions here based on your needs
        # before deleting related comments
        Comment.objects.filter(f_name=self.name).delete()
        # deleting file object itself
        super(File, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)


class Comment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=False)
```

Comment: "Django does not allow referring to non-unique field in foreign key, which is a bad practice anyway." I think this is a requirement of the underlying SQL database. So Django doesn't have any say in the matter even if it wanted to.

Comment: Your answers doesn;'t really solve the problem of a relationship between `File` and `Comment` (i.e. how would i get `File.comments`).
I think one approach is for File to have `@property def comments(self): return Comments.objects.filter(file_name=self.name)`. This works but it means that if i wanted to get all comments for 1000 files, this would trigger 1000 separate db queries. How can i improve on this?

Comment: If there are 1000 files, then you have to trigger 1000 separate db queries with this relation. However, you can use IN operator to get the data in a single query for example,`return Comment.objects.filter(file_name__in=['file1', 'file2'])`.


Please, note, IN operator has its own limitations depending on the underlying SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Comment(models.Model):
    file_object = models.ForeignKey(File, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

c1 = Comment.objects.create(file_object=f1, comment="Comment 1")
c2 = Comment.objects.create(file_object=f2, comment="Comment 2")
```

The ID's or primary keys will be added automatically and will of course need to be unique. Also the default is that unique=False elsewhere. As you can see below I have provided some examples, and tried to make it clear that we are dealing with objects:

```
my_file_objects = File.objects.filter(name="a.xlsx").all()

for file_object in my_file_objects:
    print(file_object.comment.text) 

my_comment_objects = Comment.objects.filter(file_object__name="a.xlsx").all()

for comment_object in my_comment_objects:
    print(comment_object.text)
    print(comment_object.file_object.pk)
```

Comment: It will help the OP more and future visitors, if you add some words explaining your code.

Comment: Sure, changing the Comment model is the best solution but I am not able to edit the `Comment.file_name` field so your solution above won't work for me.